# The verb "span"

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, terminology

Let $V$ be a vector space, $W$ a subspace, and $S$ a set of vectors in $V$.

I think I have come across two different definitions for "$S$ spans $W$":

1. The span of $S$ is equal to $W$
2. The span of $S$ contains $W$

And the noun "span (of a set of vectors)" to be defined as the set of all linear combinations.

Did I recall this correctly - if book references to both definitions could be provided that'd be great. (as a result I have been avoiding the verb)

Comment: "A subset $S$ spans a subspace $W$" means the span of $S$ is equal to $W$.

Comment: Is [this](https://planetmath.org/Span) helpful maybe?

Comment: Usually, when we want to know if $S$ spans $W$, we already know that $S$ is a subset of $W$. Under this hypothesis (that is assumed in the usual definitions), 1 and 2 are equivalent.

Comment: Usage 2 seems nonstandard, but I could see how it might be used informally

Comment: Any linear algebra textbook contains the definition  of the span of a set of vectors as well as an internet search. Equals is self explanatory and contains means there may be more.

Comment: I ask the question because I recall seeing definitions which go along the lines of "S spans W if every vector in W can be written as a linear combination of vectors in S", to clarify where I'm getting (2) from. Currently, I have been able to find a few sources online such as notes and MSE questions which do refer to this. I am wondering if this stems from some text defining it this way, however, hence the question and resource request.

Comment: The texts I've been able to check so far only define the noun, so the verb implicitly coincides with the noun when used.

Comment: For example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313504/what-is-the-intuitive-meaning-of-the-basis-of-a-vector-space-and-the-span and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913706/does-a-spans-b-mean-the-same-thing-as-textspana-b do refer to definition 2, but don't include the source texts. A site https://ximera.osu.edu/linearalgebra/textbook/describingVectorSpaces/spanningSets

Comment: @Shuri2060 What's still unclear for you

Comment: @Localth The question is asking if it's true that both definitions of the verb "to span" are in common use. An answer should, at minimum, contain a statement along the lines of "yes, both definitions are in common use," or "no, only definition 1 is in common use," or "no, only definition 2 is in common use." So far, neither answer post contains any such statement, which means that the question has not yet been answered.

Comment: @TannerSwett It's probably better in my opinion if the asker replies what's unclear for them after many comments rather than yourself purporting to know what's unclear to them. If you did know then you ought to have already enlightened the asker rather than doing what you've evidently been doing

Comment: If my original question wasn't clear, I hope my comments to clarify were.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Okay, could you clarify where definition 2 is mentioned in one of the links, I can only see definition 1 mentioned, which I would consider as the standard definition

Comment: 1. "A set of vectors spans a space if their linear combinations fill the space." 2. explicit reference to the issue. 3. "A collection of vectors spans a set if every vector in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in the collection."

Comment: @Shuri2060 "fill the space" is equivalent to $W$ rather than containing $W$ (it can't be a proper superset of $W$). Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The span $S$ is a vector space. If the vectors $\{v_i\}$ where $v_i\in V$, are the generators of $S$ then $S$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$.

If $S\neq\{\mathbf0\}$ then it's possible to find a subspace $U\subset V$ such that $S\supset U$.

$(\{v_i\}$ spans $W$ $\Rightarrow \operatorname{span}(\{v_i\})=W) \Rightarrow (U\subseteq W\Rightarrow\operatorname{span}(\{v_i\})\supseteq U)$

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following this answer. Are you saying that the phrase "$\{v_i\}$ spans $W$" is defined as meaning "the span of $\{v_i\}$ is equal to (and not a proper superset of) $W$"? How does the subspace $U$ come into play?

Comment: @TannerSwett Yes, if $\{v_i\}$ is a set containing multiple vectors $v_i\in V$ and the set spans $W$, the span of the set is $W$, and then all subsets of $W$ are subsets of the span of the set

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of span is correct, but I think your issue lies in the difference between the words equal and contains. The span is just the set of all linear combinations. So an example between equality vs containment might help. Thus, let us consider $u=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $v=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. Now we will have that $\text{span}(u,v)=\left\{c_1u+c_2v=\begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2\end{bmatrix}:c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. Thus, we see that $\text{span}(u,v)=\mathbb{R}^2$. However, if we consider the subspace $W=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ x\end{bmatrix}:x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ (this is just the span of the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. We have that $W$ is contained in the $\text{span}(u,v)$, but it is not equal to the span as $W$ is a one-dimensional subspace while $\text{span}(u,v)$ is a two-dimensional space, think of $W$ as the line $y=x$ sitting inside the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. I hope this example helps clarify the notion of contains vs equal. Also, I might not that if the span is equal to $W$, then it also contains $W$. That is equality implies containment; however, the converse is not true (as the above example shows).

Comment: I think the asker is already clear on the difference between containing (as a subset) and equaling; their question was whether the phrase "$S$ spans $W$" is defined as meaning "the span of $S$ is equal to $W$" or "the span of $S$ contains $W$ (as a subset, not necessarily proper)." I don't see how your post answers that question.